# To read data from Access Token - using Facebook PHP SDK v 3.2.3

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need to print the events that my friends are going to, using this application. the {user-id}/events does not work, most likely because the access tokens are not allowing it to! My friend list is already getting printed, i just need to pull out the events they are going to. I just know how to read the access token, but i have no idea how to extract data using it. I have gone through numerous answers, and most of them talk about some syntax like ->

> "GET /oauth/access_token?
>        client_id={app-id}
>       &client_secret={app-secret}
>       &grant_type=client_credentials"

...which i just don't get. Here is my code below ->

```
 $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();     
        $get_at = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $access_token;

        echo "Acess tokens in real!";    //i was just fooling here to print the token
        echo "<br />" . $get_at;

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($user_profile);
        echo "</pre>";

          $dost = $facebook->api('/me/friends','GET');

            foreach ($dost['data'] as $value) {

         $friend_id = $value['id'];
         $events = $facebook->api('/' . $friend_id . '/events'); //this should have worked, but did not!
         echo "<pre>";
         echo "Friend Name: ";
         print_r($value['name']);
         echo "<br />";
         echo "Friends events: ";
         print_r($events);
         echo "</pre>";
```

and, i am using the correct permissions too! ->

```
 $params = array(
        'scope' => 'public_profile, user_friends, email',
        'redirect_url' => 'http://xxxxxxp.com'
       );
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
```

I'm pretty sure i am missing something small...
Any ideas, champs?

Comment: does your app request the permissions to view the friends' events?

Comment: Also, assuming your app does ask for the right permissions, you need to use your app's token for the request - not your token, which is what you have in the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things you are missing. First, you are not asking for the correct permissions. If you want to read the users' events, you need to ask for the user_events permission and if you want to read friends' events, you need to ask for the friends_events permission in your scope variable of the params array:

```
$params = array(
        'scope' => 'public_profile, user_friends, email, user_events, friends_events',
        'redirect_url' => 'http://xxxxxxp.com'
       );
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Second, you need to actually pass the access token you retrieved to the api call:

```
 $events = $facebook->api('/' . $friend_id . '/events?access_token='. $get_at);
```

Comment: DAMN IT! I was missing the very base! On implementing this, the app now asks for the events permission. Bull's eye. But sadly, the event permission has to be sent to FB for review, so i cannot get a result. Facebook is so cautious, damn it. But i guess this solves it. I want u to know, that it had been days and i was getting so mad. Thank you for this man, you made my blood pressure back to normal! Cheers!

Comment: happy to have been of help- I agree with you re: Facebook documentation - it is horrendous, and I struggled with a similar issue when developing my app last year.